# DataTable to Generic List Using Task to Make it faster

Tags: c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Have started to Make the conversion faster from dataTable to List as I have 20K record in datatable and converting it in normal way takes 5 to 7 Minutes. SO I thought to Make it faster by using Parallel.ForEach or Task but still no benefit - Any suggestion please. Mu code is as below :

```
 public static List<T> FillFromStoredProc<T>(string storedproc, SqlParameter[] prms) where T : IReadOnlyDatabaseObject, new()
    {
      DataTable dt = DatabaseHelper.runStoredProc(Configuration.Instance.ConnectionString, storedproc, prms);

       ConcurrentBag<T> bag = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
        IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();

        Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, Drow => {

            bag.Add(GetFromDataRow<T>(Drow, properties));
        });

       return bag.ToList();
    }
 public static T GetFromDataRow<T>(DataRow dr, IList<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : IReadOnlyDatabaseObject, new()
    {
        T ret = new T();
        ret.LoadFromDataRowAsync(dr, properties);
        return ret;
    }
 public virtual void LoadFromDataRowAsync(DataRow dr, IList<PropertyInfo> properties)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(properties, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, prop =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains(prop.Name))
                {
                    if (prop.PropertyType.BaseType.Name == "Enum")
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(this, Enum.Parse(prop.PropertyType, dr[prop.Name].ToString()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var val = DatabaseHelper.ConvertFromDBVal(prop.GetType(), dr[prop.Name]);

                        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                        {
                            // Convert back from DB value

                            if ((DateTime)(val) == SqlDateTime.MinValue)
                            {
                                val = DateTime.MinValue;
                            }
                        }

                        prop.SetValue(this, val);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        });

    }
```

Please help me to make this faster. Thanks

Comment: 20K rows isn't a lot of data. This shouldn't even take a second. The way this code is written though it's impossible to understand what it does and what may be slow. It's probably the inefficient use of reflection. Parallelization won't solve that.

Comment: What you seem to be trying to do is what micro-ORMs like Dapper do already - execute a query or stored procedure and return strongly-typed results. They don't use DataTable and type information is extracted and cached the first time a call is made.

Comment: Using a DataTable is a problem in itself, as you have to *wait* for all the data before you have a chance to start the conversion. You should use a datareader instead to read and convert each row as it arrives. That's how ORMs (including Dapper) work

Comment: The Procedure takes only 5Sec to fetch the data -the only time is taken in the conversion . That's why I thought to go for Parallel for, and one thing You have commented on use of reflection- Can you please send some link.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting parallelism is useless and must be avoided, because usually it only makes the overall performance worse.

Your bottleneck is the reflection - it is slow.  You should come up with an alternative.  For example, you can create a base class for your generic types, and use a virtual method that maps the name of a property to an actual property.  It sounds like quite some grinding and dirty work, but it will be more efficient.

Comment: Hi Nick, Would request you to send me some code or link so that I can get a way to start. Thanks